# How to call restful webservices from Struts2?

Tags: web-services, struts2

I made small application. I made login application. I want call restful web services from action class. I used struts2 framework. I can't change restful web services. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: *Calling* a RESTful or any other service is not special in a Struts 2 action.

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma ..Can we not call from action class?

Comment: Of course you can. But Struts has nothing to do with it. Do you use any HTTP or REST client library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is solution of my question.

```
 try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ProWebservices/webresources/users/" + emailid + "&" + password + "&photographer");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            JsonObject json = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(output);
            String out = (String) json.get("userid").toString();
            if(!out.equals("null")){
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```